# Oracle: how to turn off locking of users when cloning database from template?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have Oracle 11g database template created from other database. 
The template has seed data.

After creating database from the template all not system users accounts are LOCKED.

How to prevent this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear.
Are you trying to unlock the users and prevent their passwords from expiring, or are you trying to avoid the users being locked when you initially open a database created from template?

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. I wan't to avoid users to being locked when I open the cloned database.